# Plotting three functions in the same output

Tags: matlab, ode45

I've defined the function

```
function dzdt=odefun2222(t,z)
beta=1+exp(-t); delta=1+exp(-t); rho=1+exp(-t); 
gama=exp(-t); theta=exp(-t); 
f1=1/2+1/(t+1); f2=1/2+1/(t+1);
dzdt=zeros(6,1);
dzdt(1)=z(2)-f1*z(1);
dzdt(2)=(1/4+1/(t+1)-beta)*z(1)+gama*z(3)-f1*z(2)-f1*(z(1)^2);
dzdt(3)=z(4);
dzdt(4)=gama*z(1)-delta*z(3)+theta*z(5);
dzdt(5)=z(6)-f2*z(5);
dzdt(6)=(1/4+1/(t+1)-rho)*z(5)+theta*z(3)-f2*z(6)-f2*(z(5)^2);
end
```

and I've used the commands

```
tspan = [0 20];
z0 = [0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001];
[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) odefun2222(t,z), tspan, z0);
plot(t,z(:,1),'b',t,z(:,3),'r',t,z(:,5),'g')
```

I've obtained the plotting only of z(3) and z(5), z(1) is not plotted at all. What can I do in order to get the plotting of all three functions z(1), z(3), z(5) in the same output ?

Comment: `z(:,1)`  is just covered by `z(:,5)`. Try changing `g` to `g--`, that is,  `plot(t,z(:,1),'b',t,z(:,3),'r',t,z(:,5),'g--')`

Comment: I haven't remark that z(:,1) and z(:,5) are identical. Thank you very much !